# What is the likelihood of a probability manifesting itself?

Tags: probability

The likelihood of rolling a 1 on a die is 1 in 6, but if you roll a die six times, you won't necessarily get a 1 exactly one time. If the likelihood of winning the lottery is 1 in 1,000,000, buying 1,000,000 lottery tickets doesn't guarantee a win. So what is the likelihood of a given probability manifesting itself?

Comment: Do you want to know the probability to roll *exactly* one 1 or *at least* one 1 in 6 rolls?

Comment: If you don´t give a reply we cannot help you. MSE is a participative forum.

Comment: @callculus sorry I wasn't able to reply for a while because I was away from my computer. I would want the probability of exactly one because it is a 1 in 6 probability. The probability of rolling an even number would be 3 in 6, so I would want the probability of rolling exactly three even numbers. Does that make sense?

Comment: The probability of 1/6 itself is not a hint to the nature of the question. I have the feeling that you are supposed to calculate the prob. to roll a 1 in any of the 6 rolls since the answer of the second question (lottery) is then much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can say that the 'expected' number of times a 1 appears on the die is exactly 1 time.

The probability that the 'expected event' happens is simply ${6\choose1}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot({\frac{5}{6}})^5$.

Basically, the probability that a 1 appears in any particular trial and not in any of the others is $\frac{1}{6}\cdot(\frac{5}{6})^5$. And there are six trials where the one may appear, so that multiplies the odds of this happening by ${{6}\choose{1}}=6$.

Hopefully you can try out your second example on your own.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Could you explain your solution a bit more?

Comment: Sure, added some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If something has a $1$ in $n$ chance of happening and you get $n$ attempts, the chances of it happening *at least* once are

$$1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\approx1-\frac1e=0.63212...$$

where the approximation becomes better for large $n$.

The chances of it happening *exactly* once are

$$n\frac1n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1}=\frac n{n-1}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\approx\frac n{n-1}\left(1-\frac1e\right)$$

So for large $n$, the two questions are basically the same.

Comment: Haven't you got to multiply the last expression by $n$, given that the one occurrence could happen on any of the $n$ trials?

Comment: There are $n$ ways, not only one way.

Comment: @ruffle Correct.